# Rails: Nested remote form doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails app in which I have a form that looks something like this:

```
[ Parent list item 1 ]
[ Parent list item 2 ]
[ Parent list item 3 - expanded ]
    [ Child list item 1 ]
    Child inline input       Child submit button
    ------------------

[Parent input]
Parent submit button
```

The parent entity input always works. It is a remote form, using `remote: true`. When I add a parent object it gets automatically added to the list with the other parent objects. Each parent can have many children, they are displayed and listed when the user expands the corresponding parent list item (like the example above). Users can add more children by entering a value in the `Child inline input`, this form is also using `remote: true`.

The problem I'm having is that add children element doesn't always work on the first page load. It works however if I refresh the page. I'm having a hard time to understand why this is.

When I create a parent object the following `js.erb` is rendered:

```
# screen_table_id is the list with parent objects.
# localized_strings/localized_string is the tr with the object
$("#screen_table_<%= @localized_string.screen.id %>").append("<%= j render   partial: 'localized_strings/localized_string', locals: { screen:  @localized_string.screen, localized_string: @localized_string }  %>");

# I use the best in place gem to manage inline editing
jQuery('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

The relevant parts of `localized_strings/localized_string` looks like this:

```
%tbody{ id: "localized_string_parent_#{localized_string.id}"}
  %tr
    %td.expandable-column
      Clicking this reveals the child objects

/ The list of children is initially hidden
%tbody.hidden[localized_string]

  - if localized_string.translations.any?
    / Renders the children
  %tr
    / This form doesn't work on page load, after I have added the parent
    = render "translations/inline_form", app: localized_string.screen.app,  screen: localized_string.screen, localized_string: localized_string, translation:  localized_string.translations.build
```

And `translations/inline_form` looks like this:

```
= form_for [app, screen, localized_string, translation], remote: true do |f|
  %td{ colspan: 2 }
    .inline-form-group
      = f.text_field :value, class: "form-control inline-form-control",  placeholder: "Translation value", id: "localized_string_input_# {localized_string.id}"

  %td
    / Sometimes nothing happens when I click Submit.
    = f.submit 'Add translation', class: "btn ban-success-outline"
```

The faulty flow looks like this:

1. Page load and I create a parent object (`LocalizedString`)
2. It gets added to the list correctly.
3. Expanding the new parent list element works as expected.
4. When clicking on the submit button for the child (`Translation`) does `nothing`.

Hope my question is understandable. Please comment if you have any comments or need clarification. I'm tankful for all ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that my issue was caused by invalid HTML. I previously rendered the form inside the `tr` tag, like this:

```
%tr
  = render "translations/inline_form", app: localized_string.screen.app,   screen: localized_string.screen, localized_string: localized_string, translation:   localized_string.translations.build
```

And the `inline_form` started with the `form` itself. 
Instead of doing like that I instead tried to wrap it inside a `td` tag, like this:

```
# inline_form.html.haml
%td{ colspan: 4 }
  # the form wasn't previously inside a td tag.
  = form_for [app, screen, localized_string, translation], remote: true,  style: "margin-bottom: 0" do |f|
```

I haven't seen this problem again after this. But I'm not 100% sure that it is the solution, since the problem showed up somewhat randomly.

Answer (score 5):

Ryan Bates did a great Railscast on this topic [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast). There are many interacting dependencies depending on your routes and model associations, but this RailsCast looks to be directly applicable.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out!

Comment: Also since you're already using JS, consider replacing that functionality with a react component. The [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem is outstanding and well supported. Plus it allows you to target specific UI elements like this one, with reusable components, without needing to go the route of a single page JS app a la Angular. A Flow/Backbone store might be overkill for this application but for simple components you can just utilize jQuery's ajax to do the updates within your react component.